# In MVC Razor Why are my checkboxes and dropdown not picking up the selected value or checked value on submit

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using MVC Razor View.

At the top of my form I have the following:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
```

it appears that none of my checkboxes or radiobuttons, or dropdown are working, they are all returning a value of null

checkbox : the model.Domestic is a boolean, could this be an issue? returns null

```
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Domestic.Value, new { value = Model.Domestic.Value ? "checked" : "" })&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="display-checkbox">Domestic</span>
```

radio button returns null

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Subscription_Renewal, false, new { id = "SR_ChkNo", value = "checked", onclick = "checkButtonDt();" })&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="largeText_light">N/A</span>
```

dropdown:

backend code:

```
 // Create the Categories Select List 
                var categoryList = new List<SelectListItem>();
                foreach (Category c in returned.Categories)
                {
                    categoryList.Add(new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Value = c.Category_ID.ToString(),
                        Text = c.Description,
                        Selected = (c.Category_ID == returned.Category_ID ? true : false)

                    });
                }

                returned.CategoryList = categoryList;
```

then in the View: I tried to select a entry from the selected list, and it returns 0

```
@Html.DropDownList("category", Model.CategoryList, new { @class = "input-box" })
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demo to bind data with checkbox,radiobutton and dropdownlist when posting form:

Model:

```
public class BindModel 
    {
        public List<SelectListItem> CategoryList { get; set; }
        public string Subscription_Renewal { get; set; }
        public bool Domestic { get; set; }
        public string category { get; set; }


    }
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Domestic)<span class="display-checkbox">Domestic</span>
    <input type="radio" name="Subscription_Renewal" value="Male" /><span class="largeText_light">Male</span>
    <input type="radio" name="Subscription_Renewal" value="Female" /><span class="largeText_light">Female</span>
    <input type="radio" name="Subscription_Renewal" value="Unspecified" /><span class="largeText_light">Unspecified</span>
    @Html.DropDownList("category", Model.CategoryList, new { @class = "input-box" })
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult TestBind(BindModel bindModel) {
            BindModel returned = new BindModel();
            var categoryList = new List<SelectListItem> { 
                new SelectListItem {  Value="1", Text="Category1",Selected=true}, 
                new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Category2", Selected = false }, 
                new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "Category3", Selected = false } };
            

            returned.CategoryList = categoryList;
            return View(returned);
        }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for you assistance here